# List of parameters to manipulate from an external list

Tags: manipulate

I am trying to achieve the functionality of the following command:

```
Manipulate[ z, {z, 0, 1}]
```

but with passing the list of parameters into `Manipulate` from and external list, e.g.

```
list = {z, 0, 1};
Manipulate[ z, list ]
```

but with this syntax I recieve the following error:

```
Manipulate::vsform: "Manipulate argument \!\(ToExpression[{\"z\", 0, 1}]\) does not have the correct form for a variable specification"
```

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {z, 0, 1};
Manipulate[z, Evaluate@list]
```

[image]

`Manipulate` has attribute `HoldAll`,

```
Attributes[Manipulate]
{HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected}
```

i.e.

> *all arguments to a function are to be maintained in an unevaluated form*

Using `Evaluate@list` makes `Manipulate` see `{z,0,1}` rather than the symbol `list`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what kguler has said, you can also inject with `With`:

```
With[{l = list}, Manipulate[z, l] ]
```

or

```
Manipulate[z, #] &[list]
```