# Variable range maximum for a Manipulate expression inside a module

Tags: manipulate, scoping

Let's say I have a function defined as a module where at the end I call up "Manipulate" as below:

```
a[x_]:= Module[{k},k = 2 x; Manipulate[Something[y], {y, 0, k}]
```

What does Mathematica complain about the variable`k`? It says "a variable was used where it is probably not going to be evaluated before going out of scope"

Is there any way I can fix this and achieve what I want?

Comment: Could you share minimal but complete example which reproduces the message? Take a look at notes of JF in [29461](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29461/5478). Also, Manipulate is HoldAll and usually With should be used to 'inject' variables inside holding expressions. See closely related: [72754](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72754/5478) and guidelines: [559](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/5478)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `Module` in the situation you describe. `Module` is a lexical scoping construct. The `k` give to `Module` as its 1st argument is a statically scoped variable. Your `Manipulate` expression builds its own dynamically scoping regime, so the `k` mentioned in your specification of the manipulator control `y` is in a different scope and is a different variable. Look at your code wrapped in `FullForm` to see that this is so.

The fix is to use `DynamicModule` in place of `Module`.

```
a[x_] :=
  DynamicModule[{k},
    k = 2 x;
    Manipulate[
      1/y^k,
      {y, .1, k, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]]

a[.5]
```

[image: demo]